# Excel VBA - Copy specific cells to a new sheet with double click, in next free row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying these days to make the following task:

I have a sheet which is something like a touchscreen Offer . I call it Sheet "NewOffer".
Inside this sheet there is a range of cells J7 to L27 inside which dynamically appear results (products).

What i want is to copy (with double click) the specific range, lets say J7 to L7 when i double click the first cell (J7).
and etc if i double click for example J9 to copy J9 to L9 and copy the row - range results in a new Sheet lets call it "NewOrders" in A2 to C2 cells and the next available row if its occupied.

I would ideally like to copy only the values and not the borders, colors etc..
(Sorry for my bad English :) )

Any help ?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at it yet? You can manage this using the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` Event.

Comment: I've made many attemps not one :)) But cant manage to copy range but whole row and even if i copy row its not getting added in next available but is rewriting in Target sheet in first row

Comment: Hi. Since you made some attempts please edit your question with your code, so that we can help correcting what is wrong and not propose solution you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with this. It's just a simple value transfer rather than copy, that way you don't get the formatting going along with it and it's also faster.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Target.Column = 10 Then
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Sheets("NewOrders").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("NewOrders").Range("A" & lrow + 1, "C" & lrow + 1).Value = Range(Cells(Target.Row, 10), Cells(Target.Row, 12)).Value
End If

End Sub
```

First checks that the double click happened in column J (10).
Then finds the last row on your NewOrders sheet.
Then grabs the data from column J:L and put its in the next row in columns A:C in NewOrders.

Comment: Its working but with a little bug. When i copy paste the first column which is a type of "201.301 or 204.301" style its pasting it with 201,301 and etc... Any idea why ?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. It copies the value that is in the cell directly to the other. It doesn't copy formatting.

Comment: The first column has results in format "XXX.XXX" and its copying pasting it in format "XXX,XXX" instead of a dot its copying a comma

Comment: Are you German by chance? Because that is something German configurations do. Just fix the formatting because as I said it's copying the value exactly as it is. It's still the same value but you're seeing different because you've changed some formatting. What you could do is copy the formatting from the cell you want into your NewOrders sheet so it has the same number format.

Comment: No :) I'm Greek :) . I guess its because its copying Value and not text. I will change all values in XXX-XXX.which solves the problem Thanks for your help

Comment: Its because of the comma presence. It thinks its a price. Thats why for example product code 101.110 is getting copied with 101,11

Comment: Just format the whole column the way you want it. then it solves all at once. If your problem is solved then you can mark it off as answered :)